# Improving performance of jbuilder in rails 4.1.8. It is taking 90% of the rendering time

Tags: performance, ruby-on-rails-4, view, rendering, jbuilder

I am building API using rails 4.1.8. I am using JBuilder to render the json output. Particular API is generating 1000-2000 records per call and API response time is around 1400 ms of which 1200+ ms is taken by jbuilder.

How do I reduce the time consumed by jbuilder. I tried oj with oj_mimic_json (since rails version > 4.1), the times are not improved.

Any suggestions on reducing the json rendering/serialization time?

Answer (score 1):

Use `to_json`, it much faster: https://medium.com/@lgmspb/how-we-increased-the-speed-of-json-generation-by-3000-times-ca9395ab7337#.3gciym3b6